# iPhone: How can I determine a host is reachable or not?

Tags: iphone

how can I determine a host, let's say http://myhost:8080/ is reachable or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find server is reachable with Reachability code in iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819088/how-to-find-server-is-reachable-with-reachability-code-in-iphone)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Reachability class from Apple, it has a method called `-reachabilityWithHostName:`, which will inform you if a host is reachable and which connection(s) are available (WiFi, GSM).

Check the code: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: thanks a lot. But it does work for "myhost" but it fails when port number is added. @Wolfgang Schreurs

Answer (score 0):

Use the reachability class of apple. [reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)
This might help you:)